Issue installing langchain package – numpy metadata generation failed due to missing compiler
I am attempting to install the langchain package in my Python virtual environment on Windows, but I encounter an error when it tries to install numpy. The error seems to be related to a failure in generating the package metadata for numpy, specifically because it can't locate a suitable compiler. Below is a portion of the error message:
The Meson build system
Version: 1.2.99
...
ERROR: Unknown compiler(s): [['icl'], ['cl'], ['cc'], ['gcc'], ['clang'], ['clang-cl'], ['pgcc']]
The following exception(s) were encountered:
Running `icl ""` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
Running `cl /?` gave "[WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified"
...
note: This error originates from a subprocess, and is likely not a problem with pip.

Steps Taken:
Activated my virtual environment.
Ran pip install langchain.
Environment:
OS: Windows
Python version: 3.13
pip version: (include your pip version)
Question: How can I resolve this error and successfully install the langchain package?
Potential Solutions Tried:
Updated pip and setuptools.
Attempted to install numpy directly with pip install numpy.
Verified that no Visual Studio build tools or C++ compilers are currently installed on my system.
Is there a way to bypass the compiler requirement, or do I need to install specific compilers to resolve this issue? Any help would be appreciated!

https://github.com/langchain-ai/langchain/issues/26026
Seems like this is a known problem but not resolved
